# Fractal API call does not return content

Tags: php, api, laravel

I worte some API methods with the fractal package to output content. When I call the specific resources, everything returns empty.

To check if everything is working I performed some prints of the content variables inbetween. For example, if I take the $incidents variable in the index function I get returned all entries in the database as expected.

The same is true, when I call the $collection variable in the respondWithCollection method in the API controller. The data is available here as well. But the browser output is only this:

{

```
"data": {
"headers": {}
}
}
```

To keep it simple, this is the method to show all results of a database:

```
class ApiIncidentsController extends ApiController {

    protected $incidentTransformer;
    protected $fractal;

    function __construct(IncidentTransformer $incidentTransformer){
        $this->incidentTransformer = $incidentTransformer;
        $this->beforeFilter('auth.basic', ['on' => 'post']);
        $this->fractal = new Manager();
        parent::__construct($this->fractal);
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $incidents = Incident::all();

        if( ! $incidents) {
            return Response::json([
                'error' => [
                    'message' => 'There are no incidents in the database.',
                    'code' => 100
                ]
            ], 404);
        } else {
            return $this->respond([
                'data' => $this->respondWithCollection($incidents, new IncidentTransformer),
            ]);
        }
    }
```

The API controller managing these calls is this:

```
class ApiController extends Controller {

    protected $statusCode = 200;
    protected $fractal;

    public function __construct(Manager $fractal) {
        $this->fractal = $fractal;
    }

    public function getStatusCode() {
        return $this->statusCode;
    }

    public function setStatusCode($statusCode) {
        $this->statusCode = $statusCode;
        return $this;
    }

    public function respond($data, $headers = []) {
        return Response::json($data, $this->getStatusCode(), $headers);
    }

    protected function respondWithItem($item, $callback) {
        $resource = new Item($item, $callback);
        $rootScope = $this->fractal->createData($resource);
        return $this->respondWithArray($rootScope->toArray());
    }

    protected function respondWithArray(array $array, array $headers = []) {
        return Response::json($array, $this->statusCode, $headers);
    }

    protected function respondWithCollection($collection, $callback) {
        $resource = new Collection($collection, $callback);
        $rootScope = $this->fractal->createData($resource);
        return $this->respondWithArray($rootScope->toArray());
    }
```

**Update 1**
This is the IncidentTransformer:

```
use League\Fractal\TransformerAbstract;


class IncidentTransformer extends TransformerAbstract {
    public function transform(Incident $incident) {
        return [
            'incidentReference' => $incident['incidentReference'],
            'latitude' => $incident['latitude'],
            'longitude' => $incident['longitude'],
            'archived' => (boolean) $incident['incidentArchived']
        ];
    }
}
```

**Update 2**
I tried something else, by removing the `respond` wrapper. Then everything is fine. But I want to use the respond function I wrote to abstract the code. This seems to be the issue. When I pass in the data into the function, nothing is being returned. When I dump the variable data, There is a JSON Response returned. But the respondWithCollection Method within returns an array. I don't see why this is happening. Could this be the issue?

```
I adapted the method like this:

    public function index()
    {
        $incidents = Incident::all();

        if( ! $incidents) {
            return Response::json([
                'error' => [
                    'message' => 'There are no incidents in the database.',
                    'code' => 100
                ]
            ], 404);
        } else {
            $data = $this->respondWithCollection($incidents, new IncidentTransformer);
            return $this->respond([
                'data' => $data
            ]);
        }
    }
```

But still the output is empty. So it must be something with the response function.

Comment: what does your incident transformer look like?

Comment: I edited the question for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning `Response::json()` twice.

`$this->respond` returns `Response::json`, but also `$this->respondWithCollection()` returns respondWithArray() which also does.

Try something like:

```
public function index()
{
    $incidents = Incident::all();

    if( ! $incidents) {
        return Response::json([
            'error' => [
                'message' => 'There are no incidents in the database.',
                'code' => 100
            ]
        ], 404);
    } else {
        // getCollection instead of respondWithCollection
        $data = $this->getCollection($incidents, new IncidentTransformer);
        return $this->respond([
            'data' => $data
        ]);
    }
}
```

-

```
// getCollection instead of respondWithCollection
protected function getCollection($collection, $callback) {
    $resource = new Collection($collection, $callback);
    $rootScope = $this->fractal->createData($resource);
    // don't respond again
    //return $this->respondWithArray($rootScope->toArray());
    return $rootScope->toArray();
}
```

Comment: Wow.. That is something I would have never thought about. Thank you!

Comment: But still one question is open to me. With this approach the output looks like this: { "data": { "data": [...] }} As I would like to define the containers by myself when creating the response, I would need to get rid of the inner "data" as I would like to add something like a "meta" tag manually as well

Comment: You will need to set a different [serializer in fractal](http://fractal.thephpleague.com/serializers/) for that. Possibly even making your own. You can set custom keys if you use the **JsonApiSerializer**